# i want to exclude the content inside the html tags when using str_ireplace

Tags: php, regex

I have this as a sample text

```
......
$text = "Swiss Real";
......
```

now what i do is this

```
$text = str_ireplace('swiss','<font color="red">swiss</font>',$text);
```

now my string is

```
$text is '<font color="red">swiss</font> Real'
```

now i want to do

```
$text = str_ireplace('re','<font color="red">re</font>',$text);
```

now here is my problem... i want to change only 'Real' and not the re in the 'color="red"'
how do i achieve it.
please help me.

Comment: This approach is totally unmaintainable and wrong [not mentioning that `<font>` is a deprecated tag]. If you want to generate html from you variables, use templating [which should be PHP main purpose, actually].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `boundary`

`\bre\b`

---

With `boundary` you can match characters that are surrounded by `non-word` characters..

Simply put it `\b` around a word enables you to match an individual word

---

For example for string `"Begin it in stackoverflow"` and if you want to replace `in` with `IN`

`in` regex would replace it to `"BegIN it IN stackoverflow"`

`\bin\b` regex would replace it to `"Begin it IN stackoverflow"`

Comment: if the $text would have been "Swiss Real", then also i want to change the Re in real and not the re in color="red".... will now your solution work

Comment: i got the example that you posted... but i want the first part with the exception that the text inside the tags be left alone.... like i want the re in the font tag left alone but the re in the $text = "Swiss Real" be changed...

Comment: @GauravBansal you can use this regex then `(?<!")re`

Comment: ok so i should use this
 $text = str_ireplace('(?<!")re','<font color="red">re</font>',$text);

Comment: @GauravBansal you can also use `(?<!"\s*)re` if there can be any spaces in the color value

Comment: @GauravBansal yes...you can use it